# Sharepoint Infopath Autofill fields

Tags: sharepoint, office365, infopath, autofill

I have a problem in autofilling data. We have just moved from SP on-premise to Office365.
In on-premise data we have used following instructions:
****substring-after(userName(),"\")
query using user info list
**set field value DisplayName=concat("i:0#w.domain|username","\").****
se**t field values of email and phone number.
But it do not work in Office 365. I have used just userName() function to autofill username but how do I get other two fields as follows.
**substring-after(userName(),"\")
query using user info list
**set field value DisplayName=userName().
set field values of email and phone.**
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on InfoPath on O365, and I am able to create a data connection to the User Information List. Please check image to see how it looks like:

[Connection to UIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhqEm.png)

Then on Form Load, I create a simple Rule that queries data using that connection. It's straightforward, in this rule run the following actions in order:

1. Set field's value: Name = userName()
2. Query using a data connection: User Information List (name of your connection)
3. Set field's value: email = EMail (and repeat this for rest of attributes)

The idea of this connection is simple, you set the "queryFields" as needed (in our case, query data where Name = userName()) , then do the query, then collect your data..that's it!

Comment: Thanks, I have those formula rules running but it does not show up.just want to confirm Email was a from data field in user information list right?

Comment: Yes, it shows as "Work email" as you see in the image in the answer above.

Comment: I have tried it already but did not autofill it. The same code works  fine for sharepoint on-premise but not with the O365

Comment: Hi @RAYash the problem  is when I see the user information list there is no data filled up for work email and other attributes that is what causing problem ( not sure but that might be a reason i guess).

Comment: sorry i refer form load  rules here

Comment: Users must have access to the site or they must login to the site at least once to have all fields in User Information List filled properly. If possible, try to query a user who has logged into the site at least once and see if this makes a difference. Otherwise, it might be a user profile related issue where properties/attributes are not properly synced and your admin should be able to fix this. Let us know how it goes! good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sure I would let you know.